# Is there a method that returns only the match or first variable match of a RegEx in ActionScript or null?

Tags: javascript, regex, actionscript-3

Is there a method yet that returns only a match and null if there is no match?

It may be a brain freeze but is there a method that just returns the match and null if not?

For example, if I want to just return the first variable or null otherwise:

```
var value:String = "image/png".toLowerCase();
var result:String = value.find(/image/(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)/);

if (result=="png") {
    // do something
}
```

I know there's `replace` and `exec` and `match` and they return arrays etc but I'm just looking for a method that returns my first match or null.

If there isn't this a function like this, I wish there was. How to god I wish there was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no specific method that does that. The closest method is `String.match` or `RegExp.exec` and it makes little difference here since the regex has no global modifier. Once you use a regex with a global modifier, you will have no choice but to use `RegExp.exec`.

Using `String.match` or `RegExp.exec` you can check if the result is `null` and if it's not `null` then extract the Group 1 value to check if it is `png`:

```
var pattern:RegExp = /image\/(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)/; 
var str:String = "image/png".toLowerCase(); 
var m:Array = pattern.exec(str); 
if (m != null) 
{ 
    if (m[1] == "png") {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Note that a `/` must be escaped in a regex literal.

You can also contract the pattern a bit to `(png|jpe?g|gif)`, but though it will work better internally, it will become less readable.

Comment: This solves the problem but are you saying that `exec` is the closest function that exists for what I want to do?

Comment: You just need to access Group 1. Using `String.match` or `RegExp.exec`, that makes little difference here since the regex has no global modifier. Once you use a regex with a global modifier, you will have no choice but to use `RegExp.exec`.